# SQL Server 2005 Query to pivot data

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a table set up like this

```
Project   Category   Date       Hours
Proj1     test       8/2/2010   2
Proj1     test       8/3/2010   8
Proj1     test       8/4/2010   4
Proj1     test       8/5/2010   3
Proj1     test       8/6/2010   5
```

I want to develop a query where you can input a saturday(Week Ending) date and get a result like this

```
WeekEnding Project Category  SunHrs MonHrs TuesHrs WedHrs ThuHrs FriHrs SatHrs  
8/7/2010   Proj1   test      0      2      8       4      3      5      0
```

Thank you

Comment: Which bit are you having trouble with?

Comment: I know how parameters work but I don't know how to pivot the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way. It looks kind of kludgey, but then pivots always look that way to me.

```
DECLARE @Saturday datetime

SET @Saturday = 'Aug 7, 2010'

SELECT
   @Saturday       WeekEnding
  ,Project
  ,Category
  ,isnull([1], 0)  SunHrs
  ,isnull([2], 0)  MonHrs
  ,isnull([3], 0)  TueHrs
  ,isnull([4], 0)  WedHrs
  ,isnull([5], 0)  ThuHrs
  ,isnull([6], 0)  FriHrs
  ,isnull([7], 0)  SatHrs
 from (select Project, Category, Datepart(dw, Date) DOW, Hours
        from MyTable
        --  Fixed bug from -7 to -6
        where Date between dateadd(dd, /*-7*/ -6, @Saturday) and @Saturday) Source
  pivot (max(Hours)
         for DOW in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7]) ) as pvt
```

I used the following to set up data to test this with:

```
DROP TABLE MyTable
CREATE TABLE MyTable
 (
    Project    varchar(10)  not null
   ,Category   varchar(10)  not null
   ,Date       datetime     not null
   ,Hours      int          not null
 )

INSERT MyTable
 values 
('Proj1', 'test', '8/2/2010',  2 ),
('Proj1', 'test', '8/3/2010',  8 ),
('Proj1', 'test', '8/4/2010',  4 ),
('Proj1', 'test', '8/5/2010',  3 ),
('Proj1', 'test', '8/6/2010',  5 )
```

Comment: You need to check `@@datefirst` if using `datepart` with `dw` and if his datetimes have any time component other than midnight `between` won't count these as being on Saturday.

Comment: @Marting, yeah, I meant to mention that there's lots of caveats when using day-of-week logic... but I forgot, since the data sample was so small.

Comment: I ran SELECT @@DATEFIRST; and it returned 7
I have the app setup so they can only enter the date and not the time

Comment: So long as you *know* that @@Datefirst will always return 7 anywhere and everywhere your code will run, your good. If you're paranoid, you have to code for the possibility that the value may vary from server to server.

Comment: where Date between dateadd(dd, -7, @Saturday)

should that 7 be a six?

Comment: Yep, that should be a -6. (My excuse is typical: insufficient testing data led to poor debugging.)

Answer (score 3):

Couple of good articles to help:

http://www.devx.com/dbzone/Article/28165

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx

Comment: Agreed, @Joshua won't the PIVOT command do exactly what you want?